# Сложный запрос, ManyToMany

Tags: sql

Я в SQL новичок. Есть запрос, над которым бьюсь уже сутки, и не понимаю как подступиться к нему, хотя, наверное, он не такой и сложный.

Суть:

Есть таблицы:
 - companies(id, name), 
 - customers(id, name), 
 - projects(id, name, cost),
 а также companies_projects(company_id, project_id) и customers_projects(customer_id, project_id). Связь **ManyToMany**.
 
Помимо этого есть еще таблицы, но они не участвуют в данном запросе.

Необходимо найти клиента для каждой компании, который приносит этой компании наименьшую прибыль. То есть, получается, сумма cost project'ов этого клиента в компании наименьшая среди остальных клиентов, которые имеют проекты в этой компании.
Вывести, соответственно, companies.name, customers.name.

Буду благодарен вам за помощь, так как сам я даже не понимаю, в каком направлении двигаться.

Comment: компания с клиентом как связана?

Comment: Через проекты. Ну то есть нет таблицы companies_customers(company_id, customer_id). Не знаю, конечно, насколько это верно, но я подумал, что такая связь будет излишней, ведь всех клиентов компании можно узнать, исходя из проектов, которая она ведет. Если это неверный подход, поправьте меня.

Answer (score 0):

в projects я бы добавил customer_id company_id
так было бы проще делать агреггирующие запросы

тем не менее используем функцию SUM

SELECT SUM(p.cost) as customer_agg_cost, cu.name as customer_name,co.name as company name FROM projects p LEFT JOIN customers_projects cup ON (p.id=cup.project_id) LEFT JOIN customers cu ON (cup.customer_id=cu.id) LEFT JOIN companies_projects cop ON (p.id=cop.project_id) LEFT JOIN companies co ON (cop.company_id=co.id) GROUP BY cup.customer_id ORDER BY customer_agg_cost

Comment: К сожалению, консоль ругается: "ОШИБКА:  столбец "cu.name" должен фигурировать в предложении GROUP BY или использоваться в агрегатной функции". Как бы обойти это?..

Comment: и так тоже как я понимаю ошибка?

SELECT SUM(p.cost) as customer_agg_cost, cu.name as customer_name FROM projects p LEFT JOIN customers_projects cup ON (p.id=cup.project_id) LEFT JOIN customers cu ON (cup.customer_id=cu.id) GROUP BY cup.customer_id ORDER BY customer_agg_cost

надо бы конкретно субд вашу знать, мой пример для MySQL и он рабочий

Comment: Да, тоже самое :( У меня PostgreSQL.

Comment: а так

 SELECT SUM(p.cost) as customer_agg_cost, cu.name FROM projects p LEFT JOIN customers_projects cup ON (p.id=cup.project_id) LEFT JOIN customers cu ON (cup.customer_id=cu.id) GROUP BY cu.name ORDER BY customer_agg_cost

Comment: Так он просто выдает сумму затрат для каждого клиента.

Comment: числа совпадают или нет, по customer-у у которого несколько проектов?
агрегация cost работает?

Comment: Да, агрегация работает правильно, выводится корректная сумма cost проектов для каждого customer.

Comment: SELECT SUM(p.cost) as customer_agg_cost, cu.name as customer_name, (SELECT name FROM companies c1 LEFT JOIN companies_projects c2 ON (c1.id = c2.company_id ) WHERE c2.project_id = p.id) AS company_name FROM projects p LEFT JOIN customers_projects cup ON (p.id=cup.project_id) LEFT JOIN customers cu ON (cup.customer_id=cu.id) GROUP BY cu.name ORDER BY customer_agg_cost 

вот с company_name

Comment: LIMIT только установите нужный

Comment: Мне, если честно, дико неудобно перед Вами за то, что Вы столько времени мне уделили. Сейчас выдает следующую ошибку "ОШИБКА:  подзапрос использует негруппированный столбец "p.id" из внешнего запроса
СТРОКА 1: ...ON (c1.id = c2.company_id ) WHERE c2.project_id = p.id) AS c..."

Comment: у меня  PostgreSQL под рукой нет к сожалению. негде потыкаться.
все мои дальнейшие советы сведутся к ничему, нужен  PostgreSQL-маньяк

Comment: Уже устанавливаю MySQL, буду пробовать на нем!)